# Showing the mean line in a density plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I create a graph using the .plot() method

```
df['age'].plot(kind='density')
```

[image]

I dont create the graph using the "plt" object: is there any way to show a dotted line as the mean using an argument of .plot().

It's always very unclear to me how to handle the attribute and the difference between plt like:

```
x = df['age'].values
result = plt.hist(x, bins=15, color='c')
plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='b', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Moreover, how can I annotate the value of the mean close to the dotted line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# Set seed to reproduce the results
np.random.seed(42)
# Generate random data
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(age=(np.random.uniform(-20, 50, 100))))

# KDE plot
ax = df['age'].plot(kind='density')
# Access the child artists and calculate the mean of the resulting array
mean_val = np.mean(ax.get_children()[0]._x)
# Annotate points
ax.annotate('mean', xy=(mean_val, 0.008), xytext=(mean_val+10, 0.010),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )
# vertical dotted line originating at mean value
plt.axvline(mean_val, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Slice 0 was selected as it corresponds to the position of the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` axes object.

```
>>> np.mean(ax.get_children()[0]._x)
14.734316880344197
```